# I'm using the reflect class to get the variables name and type but i can't find

Tags: java, api

I'm using the Field calss form reflect package or api, to find the variables name and type but i can't get it's value

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field; 

public class Ushtrimi2{
    
    boolean  b= false;
    byte B= 43;
    char a = 'A';
    short n = 33;
    int N = 3232432;
    long r = -325544332;
    float f = 43.5435f;
    double I = 345.2353422423;
        
    public static void main(String[] ags){
        
        
        Ushtrimi2 ushtrimi = new Ushtrimi2();
        Class ushtrimiVar = ushtrimi.getClass();
        
        Field[] fields = ushtrimiVar.getDeclaredFields();
        for(Field field : fields) { 
        System.out.println("Variable name : "+ field.getName());
        System.out.println("TYPE:" + field.getType());
        // System.out.println(field.getValue()) or something like this 
        }
        
    }
}
```

The output is this is there a methode to let me call or access the value of the variable that is stored in the fields array

```
alban@alban-HP-ProBook-4540s:~/Documents/CSE/SHK/Ushtrimet/Ushtrime_2$ java Ushtrimi2.java 
Variable name : b
TYPE:boolean
Variable name : B
TYPE:byte
Variable name : a
TYPE:char
Variable name : n
TYPE:short
Variable name : N
TYPE:int
Variable name : r
TYPE:long
Variable name : f
TYPE:float
Variable name : I
TYPE:double
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the access level if it has been private:

```
field.setAccessible(true);
```

And then get up value like that:

```
field.get(ushtrimi)
```

when `ushtrimi` is object for reading a field:

Change your code like that:

```
public static void main(String[] ags){


    Ushtrimi2 ushtrimi = new Ushtrimi2();
    Class ushtrimiVar = ushtrimi.getClass();

    Field[] fields = ushtrimiVar.getDeclaredFields();
    for(Field field : fields) {
        System.out.println("Variable name : "+ field.getName());
        System.out.println("TYPE:" + field.getType());
        field.setAccessible(true);
        try {
            System.out.println(field.get(ushtrimi));
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // System.out.println(field.getValue()) or something like this
    }

}
```

And you can see this output:

```
Variable name : b
TYPE:boolean
false
Variable name : B
TYPE:byte
43
Variable name : a
TYPE:char
A
Variable name : n
TYPE:short
33
Variable name : N
TYPE:int
3232432
Variable name : r
TYPE:long
-325544332
Variable name : f
TYPE:float
43.5435
Variable name : I
TYPE:double
345.2353422423

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Ushtrimi2.java:24: error: unreported exception IllegalAccessException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
  System.out.println(field.get(ushtrimi));